# can't get virtualhost run on different port

Tags: apache, virtualhost, ports

I'm trying to setup on ubuntu, virtualhosts on different ports, but I can get it work. My configuration in sites-available looks like

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:5050
Listen 5050
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:5050>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot "/var/www/example"
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/example/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and I added to the host file

```
127.0.0.1:5050 localhost
```

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the `hosts` file accepts that kind of notation? I've never seen anything like it. What happens if you open `127.0.0.1:5050`?

Comment: Doesn't seems to work, I've been changing the hosts now to 127.0.0.1:5050. What would be great if I could run a localhost:80 and another one on port higher than 4000

Answer (score 1):

The `hosts` file maps names to ip addresses.  It cannot be used to do anything with ports.  You may only specify ports as part of your url (such as `http://localhost:5050/`).

You can certainly run virtual hosts on ports other than 80, but you have to explicitly reference the port as I've indicated.

Comment: I have been removing from hosts the referenced line but without any results

Comment: What doesn't work? Show the actual commands that you're running and any error messages that output when not working as expected.  Use `curl` or `wget` for testing things, since these are command line tools and friendlier for this sort of thing.

Comment: okay I've been figure out that the port has to be activated in /etc/apache2/ports.conf but now is pointing to another directory root and I can not find the configuration where is this enabled?My error log shows that the webroot is on /etc/apache2/htdocs located, and the virtualhost is pointing to /var/www/example